# Read multiple yamls in a file

Tags: go, yaml

How does one parse multiple yamls in a file similar to how kubectl does it?

**example.yaml**

```
---
a: Easy!
b:
  c: 0
  d: [1, 2]
---
a: Peasy!
b:
  c: 1000
  d: [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference in behavior between gopkg.in/yaml.v2 and gopkg.in/yaml.v3:

V2: https://play.golang.org/p/XScWhdPHukO
V3: https://play.golang.org/p/OfFY4qH5wW2

Both implementations produce an incorrect result IMHO but V3 is apparently slightly worse.

There's a workaround. If you slightly change code in the accepted answer, it works correctly and in the same fashion with both versions of yaml package: https://play.golang.org/p/r4ogBVcRLCb

Comment: The result is not _incorrect_, the usage of the parser is. In the first two examples you parse different documents into the same object and the result is actually what I would expect - existing values in the struct are left as they are, while new values are written. The "workaround" you mention is the correct way to use the parser.

Comment: That's right, @lmazgon. At the time I was writing the answer I was just starting with Go. Seems obvious now, though still depends on the library implementation. In fact, I was too surprized with the difference between library versiosn at first, didn't think it through.

Answer (score 3):

Current `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` `Decoder` produces quite correct result, you just need to pay attention when creating new structure for each document and check it was parsed correctly (with `nil` check), and handle `EOF` error correctly:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
import "os"
import "errors"
import "io"

type Spec struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("spec.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    d := yaml.NewDecoder(f)
    for {
        // create new spec here
        spec := new(Spec)
        // pass a reference to spec reference
        err := d.Decode(&spec)
        // check it was parsed
        if spec == nil {
            continue
        }
        // break the loop in case of EOF
        if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("name is '%s'\n", spec.Name)
    }
}
```

Test file `spec.yaml`:

```yaml
---
name: "doc first"
---
name: "second"
---
---
name: "skip 3, now 4"
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution I found using `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type T struct {
        A string
        B struct {
                RenamedC int   `yaml:"c"`
                D        []int `yaml:",flow"`
        }
}

func main() {
    filename, _ := filepath.Abs("./example.yaml")
    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    r := bytes.NewReader(yamlFile)

    dec := yaml.NewDecoder(r)

    var t T
    for dec.Decode(&t) == nil {

      fmt.Printf("a :%v\nb :%v\n", t.A, t.B)

    }
}
```